# 70915 Two-Face Double Demolition excavator gun won't load

Tags: sets

I just finished putting together Two-Face Double Demolition and I went to load the gun on the excavator but part #6097090 six shooter trigger is too tall for the bullets to be loaded.  Any idea how I can load the "bullets" when they don't fit?

The picture on the box of the trigger shows just the trigger point and  not that big circle where the bullets fit

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you don't have the white round piece pushed in far enough. It should be sitting further in, so you can load the 1x1 round plates (bullets) over it.

Comment: Pliers was needed to pop the two pieces together.  Some people won't be able to press them together by hand.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it to work. :)